# Setting vcap.me entries in hosts file

Tags: cloud-foundry

An answer with a question...

I did a single node cloud foundry install that I am running in Workstation and I am connecting to that machine from anther VM.  I put the following entries in my hosts file on that second VM:

```
192.168.0.111  api.vcap.me
192.168.0.111  vcap.me
```

A

```
vmc target api.vcap.me
```

worked fine but when I did a

```
vmc register
```

and entered my email and password (+verify) it appeared to create the user but then failed on login with the following error:

```
Problem with login to 'http://api.vcap.me', target refused connection 
(Connection refused - connect(2)), try again or register for an account.
```

running

```
vmc login
```

resulted in the same error.  Running

```
vmc -trace login
```

showed that uaa.vcap.me was being contacted so I added that to my hosts file and bingo - it worked.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this easily overlooked requirement. A meta comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question (see [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/45773)), but please do so with an explicit answer rather than merging it with the question - like so your question won't show up as 'unanswered' anymore, which is desirable to make room for all those really unanswered questions; besides you'll likely gain more reputation ;)

Comment: You know, I looked into that, but since I had just signed up for StackOverflow (I know, right?) I wasn't allowed.  Thanks for confirming the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

login uses uaa so you would need to also add uaa url into your hosts file.

```
192.168.0.113       uaa.vcap.me
```